# The fastest way to do RPC

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, c#-4.0, tcp

I am evaluating an alternative to WCF using TCP sockets.
The main objective is to create a server alternative for a WCF Service.
The goal is to create a higly performant and reliable alternative for a duplex WCF Service with potentially hundreads of clients.

Question:

- Has someone tried something like this?
- What is your experience?
- Is connection handling reliable?
- Is it more efficient than a good optimized wcf service?
- Is it worth the effort?

Comment: This all sounds highly subjective and dependent on your specific needs, but yes: WCF does add features, flexibility convenience and abstraction at the expense of overheads and performance.

Comment: Have you looked at tools like servicestack? Not sure if that does duplex, though

Comment: How many months are you prepared to invest?

Comment: max 2 months for a working prototype

Comment: @MarcGravell it seems that it doesn't support duplex, so a no go

Comment: i have found a library called zeromq. Seems like worth to take a look. has someone experience with that library???